# What is the suitable word here? "granted" loan or "allotted" loan, or "provided" loan or any better word?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

Imagine this situation: the minister of a state announces, "from the next month onwards, all the employees of the Municipality can avail education loans for their children from any of the government banks." (He announces this on behalf of the government)

'education loan' is something that the employees avail only when they need money for their children's education. So, even if the government makes the announcement in 2017, the employees might not use it immediately. They would use it only when their children grow up and need that money(say sometime in 2019 or later, when their children got admission in any college).

so, If I am a reporter asking the municipality employees, how should I frame the following sentence?

- Has the Government **sanctioned** education loans for your children?
  or
- Has the Government **granted** you the education loans for your children?

Is there any better word?

I think we use the word 'sanction' only after we apply for the loan in any bank and the bank approves it, but not when the govt. passes an order about it.

please help.

Comment: Is the reporter asking about a loan spoken about now but not yet taken, or is the reporter set in a future time, asking whether the loan has been taken (but worded to reflect the government's end of the transaction)?

Comment: Let's say the minister made the announcement today in a meeting with all the employees of the municipality office. News Reporters were not allowed into the meeting hall. After the meeting got over, the minister left and, the reporters were asking the employees if the minister has "GRANTED" or "SANCTIONED' any loans? I want the appropriate word.

Comment: At that point, the minister would probably have only had time to *announce* the loans.

Comment: Thank you. But, what if the reporter asks the question after an act is made regarding the loans?

Comment: If you mean *when the loan is made*, it doesn't matter that the lender is the government. The lender has *extended* the loan to the borrower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Promulgate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/promulgate):

> to make known by open declaration; publish; proclaim formally or put into operation (a law, decree of a court, etc.).

To say "The Government *promulgated* education loans for the children of government workers" means that the government has formally proclaimed the loans or has put a loan apparatus into place.

(You would not say the government has *granted* educational loans: this would imply that the contracts are already in place.)

Answer (score 1):

How about [authorized](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/authorize)?

From dictionary.com -

> **authorize** [aw-thuh-rahyz]
>
> *to give authority for; formally sanction (an act or proceeding):*
>
> *example:* Congress authorized the new tax on tobacco.

So for your case, you could say - "*Congress **authorised** education loans to the children of municipality employees*"

Comment: Thank you. So, can I say "Congress authorised education loans to the children of municipality employees?"

Comment: exactly. Edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Has the government **declared** any education loans for your children?

> **[declare](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/declare)** :
>
> ***to announce something clearly, firmly, publicly, or officially***

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the government holds a press conference to say that it is making the loans available to employees. Your term *announce* fits here - the government *announces* the (availability of) loans.

> **announce** *verb*
>   1 (*reporting verb*) Make a formal public statement about a fact, occurrence, or intention.
>   (*with clause*) ‘the President's office announced that the siege would be lifted’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/announce)

Now suppose a municipal employee goes to a government bank to apply for such a loan. Once the bank applies due process and determines that the municipal employee qualifies, it can be said to have *approved* the loan. At this point, no money has yet changed hands.

> **approve** *verb*
>   1 Officially agree to or accept as satisfactory.
>   ‘the budget was approved by parliament’
>   ‘What we have here as a problem is a lack of prudence in approving a loan proposal.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/approve)

Some time later, the employee takes the money out to pay for their child's education. At that point, the loan is said to have been *drawn down*.

> **draw something down**
>   1.1 Withdraw money from a fund or loan facility.
>   ‘I'm not actually going to be drawing down any of the loan until early 1999’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/draw)